# jQuery clone isn't styled

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop

To get around the fact that the thing I'm dragging is inside a parent container that I need to drag it out of, I'm using a clone to drag instead.

```
$(".innerEvent").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    appendTo: "body"
});
```

This works perfectly except that the font goes from pretty to ugly. Why isn't the clone inheriting the style of the original? Or is there some other issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably the style is defined in a a `"parentContainer child"` style which is broken when you clone the element and attach it directly to the body.

Try to improve your style definitions to target the cloned entity as well.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. I didn't expect that it wouldn't inherit the original's, parent's style, but I guess it makes sense.